# I am confused, so many forums now. Which one to use for Mathematica?

Tags: support

Sorry if a basic questions, but I am starting to get confused as to where to go to ask Mathematica questions now.

I see this page which shows 4 questions on it.

1. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions

and this page shows many more questions but does not have the 'newest' option on it.

2. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

What is (1) for, and how is it different from the (2) above?

This site, which is tagged Mathematica, has the newest option on it.

3. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mathematica

Should I stop using the last one above? Is it possible to add 'newest' option to the (2) link above?

And why when I click https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/unanswered I see questions with answers on them?

Basically, my main question really: should I be using (3) or (2) to post question on Mathematica from now on? And is it possible to merge all the questions/content that is (3) into (2) so that one does not keep jumping from one site to another?

Comment: Yeah, it would be good if you can ask your *Mathematica* questions here instead of on SO from now on. We need to grow this site...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. is the complete list of all questions on this site; I don't know why you're only seeing 4 questions, but there should be many more than that.
2. is a different view of the same site, which shows the "hot" questions (the ones which have had recent activity, i.e. have been answered or edited recently).
3. is the list of Mathematica questions on Stack Overflow, which is an entirely different site. That is where many Mathematica questions were posted prior to this site opening up. Since this site is in private beta, people who were not invited to the beta will still have to post their Mathematica questions there for the next week.

If you would like to post a question about Mathematica, use this link:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

That corresponds to options (1) and (2) from your question, i.e. this site, not Stack Overflow.

The questions from Stack Overflow will not be merged to this site, but people will surely re-ask some of them here.

Comment: Since you've covered most points, I'll just make this remark – how soon a question shows up on the front page depends on the site's activity. On [so] it is near instant, whereas here (and on beta sites in general), it takes a while. I asked the first question on mma.se and for a full 5 minutes, I couldn't see it on the front page or /newest/

Comment: And one more remark: A question with an answer counts as unanswered if the answer has not received an upvote.